# EF Core ThenInclude retrieves all nested data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have multiple related objects that are exposed through API in a JSON format as:

```
{
    "name": "Building 1",
    "country": {
      "text": "USA",
      "value": 2,
      "states": [
        {
          "text": "Alabama",
          "value": 2,
          "cities": []
        },
        {
          "text": "Alaska",
          "value": 4,
          "cities": []
        },
        {
          "text": "Arizona",
          "value": 7,
          "cities": []
        },
        {
          "text": "Arkansas",
          "value": 11,
          "cities": []
        }
      ]
    },
    "id": 4
  }
```

Building table has columns as `"CountryId"`, `"StateId"`, `"CityId"`

The below code is supposed to bring buildings in which country, state and a city explicitly based on the relationships.

```
_dbContext.Buildings.Include(o => o.Country).ThenInclude(s => s.States).ThenInclude(c => c.Cities).ToListAsync();
```

Once the query is executed, the country entity brings every single States that are not even related to this particular building.

The desired result should be as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Building 1",
    "country": {
      "text": "USA",
      "value": 2,
      "states": [
        {
          "text": "Alabama",
          "value": 2,
          "cities": []
        }
      ]
    },
    "id": 4
  }
```

Is there a possible issue with the `ThenInclude` query or any other solution exists for it?

Appreciated.

Comment: I think you should improve your data structure. the `building` object should have a country AND state AND city information imho.

Comment: @ilkerkaran Building entity has its objects in it. However, in order to come up with the desired look as above, I'd like to have the related objects appear as in nested. Does this make sense?

Comment: I found out that, but with this approach, your structure false leading about the relations. i.e. your building has only a country reference on it and nothing more according to the current structure. So exposing your data as above is ok but persisting them is not right according to normalization etc.

Comment: What you are saying is that due to the incompetence of the table structure, ThenInclude does not really function properly?

Comment: no you should not use `ThenInclude` to fill object relations.becuase they are designed for nested object relations. When you put ThenInclude to State it fills States relations, but you ened that stats parents relations. So `ThenInclude` is not what you looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a building is required to have a State, then there would be no need for a Country, that can be retrieved through the State. Having both State and Country can easily lead to inconsistent data state, for instance if the initial state reads State = California, Country = USA, some system could change Country to point to "Canada" without changing the state, or change the state without changing the country, resulting in Building.State.Country <> Building.Country. If a Building requires a City, then the State and Country can be inferred from the city. Having multiple FK's denormalizes the structure and can easily lead to inconsistencies.

To the source of the issue, Entities should always reflect the complete data state, not the filtered state you might want to present to the view. If you give a Building a direct reference to it's Country, then serializing Country will include *all* referenced States for that country because that reflects what a Country is. You don't want the Country, you just want the country data with the relevant state and city that is applicable to that building in a specific format.

That is the responsibility for View Models or DTO, so leverage projection to turn entities into the structure you want to pass back to the view/consumer:

```
[Serializable]
public class BuildingViewModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public BuildingCountryViewModel Country { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BuildingCountryViewModel
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public BuildingStateViewModel State { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BuildingStateViewModel
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public BuildingCityViewModel City { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BuildingCityViewModel
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then...

```
var building = context.Buildings.Where(x => x.Name == "Building 1")
   .Select(x => new BuildingViewModel
   {
      Name = x.Name,
      Country = x.City.State.Country.Select(c => new BuildingCountryViewModel
      {
          Text = c.Text,
          Value = c.Value,
          State = x.City.State.Select(s => new BuildingStateViewModel
          {
             Text = s.Text,
             Value = s.Value,
             City = x.City.Select(ci => new BuildingCityViewModel
             {
                Text = ci.Text
             }
          }
       }
    }).Single();
```

The entities reflect the complete data state, as such if a building must belong to a city then we don't need to de-normalize it just because we might want to display it in a different format. (Country -> State -> City) The above example assumes City is required, and interpolates the City => State => Country relation with just a City reference on the Building into what the view model would display.

Comment: I understand your point and it makes sense. There are DTO classes in the project, apparently. So it could be utilised. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
_dbContext.Buildings.Include(c => c.Cities).ThenInclude(s => s.States).ThenInclude(o => o.Country).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: OP tries to filter included data since they do not need all nested data. So your answer is not solving it